# Is there a way to have one series name for multiple series without duplicating the series name in the tooltip?

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, r-highcharter

I have the following code chunk:

```
  series_name = "Census" 

  # Default plot settings
  hc = highchart(type="stock") %>%
    hc_add_series(data = census.by.day, hcaes(x = time_ts, y = census, group = area), type = "line", name = series_name) %>%
    hc_legend(enabled=TRUE) %>%
    hc_tooltip(crosshairs = TRUE, backgroundColor = "#FCFFC5",shared = TRUE, borderWidth = 1, split = FALSE,
               pointFormat = '<b>{series.name}</b><br>{point.area}: {point.y:.0f} <br>') %>%
    hc_xAxis(title=list(text="Date Hour")) %>%
    hc_chart(backgroundColor="white")
```

In this example, the user can select multiple "areas" which in turn will update the hcaes(group = var) to create more than one series for each area. I'm trying to figure out how to keep a single series name for when the user selects more than one area. Right now, the series name is being duplicated because I have it in the tooltip. So the tooltip is repeated for each potential series.
[image: hc plot]

In the example above, I only want to "Census" once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this by using the tooltip.formatter function from Highcharts JS API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.formatter

Here you can find an article that may be helpful to learn how to work with Highcharts JS API in R: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR3b9X-GsVfGT_QVWFALi0KOJ83XbWoKTK1HQA4459U4NNg0UTEDXG-MGss